# 2 different users accessing internet banking from mobile browser at different time but IP address and user agent string is exactly the same

Tags: isp, user-agent

Is it possible to have a scenario where there are 2 different users accessing internet banking (using their own credentials) from mobile browser at different time using the **same mobile device**, **but carrying the same IP address and the same user agent string** ? What about if these two users access from their own mobile device - will it be possible to have the same IP address and the exact match of user agent string?

Comment: Yes, why not? But in the first place, do you mean *same device* or *same model*? Big difference.

Comment: It is _possible_ for a mis-configured (or "spoofed") device... But... Neither would work properly. Unless there is some kind of NAT (Network Address Translation) involved, every IP must be unique. If they were not, how could a router know where to send "You balance is -10" to one IP in China versus the same IP in USA? It could not know. UA strings, however, are easily faked/spoofed.

Comment: @DanielB the exact same device. 1st user accesses the website in the morning and the 2nd user accesses at noon. Is there any specific criteria that would differentiate these 2 users even though they are using the same device ?

Answer (score 1):

> but carrying the same IP address

Yes, pretty much all home Internet connections use NAT for sharing just 1 IPv4 address between all devices in that home. Many smaller business connections will have just one IP address, too. And most importantly, many *public wi-fi* networks do the same. So whether it's at the same time or at different times, people using the same network end up having the same address.

But it is *also* possible for the address to match in other situations as well. Mobile (4G/LTE) connections are often short-lived and the same IP address may "move around" – although not exactly *shared,* the same address might get assigned to different 4G users at different times (possibly even within the same day).

> and the same user agent string

Yes, it's certainly possible that two people in the same household will have the same iPhone model running the same Safari browser, for example – or be using the same version of Chrome on Windows 10. In an enterprise environment you could have *hundreds* of people running the same browser on the same OS and having the same UA, all behind a single IPv4 address (or a very small NAT pool).

User-Agent is not suitable for distinguishing clients. That is not its purpose.

> Is there any specific criteria that would differentiate these 2 users even though they are using the same device ?

Websites typically use HTTP cookies for that. They issue a "session ID" cookie to recognize the same browser instance over time.